# What programming languages are installed in Windows XP by Default

Tags: windows, programming-languages

Where I am at, it is not allowed to install any software. I need to automate some tasks and I cannot do it in powershell because it is not allowed. Are there any languages already installed on windows that i can use to automate and probably integrate with microsoft office?

Comment: Batch, VBScript? Not sure about office though

Comment: Talk to your manager and get him to authorise Powershell. If you can't do your job because of the lack of tools - that's the real problem that needs addressing.

Comment: Thou shalt not install external programs... you know, for security reasons. But thou shalt run on Windows. Hmmm

Comment: OP is not alone -..-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can run VBScript and JScript through Windows Script Host. While using these languages, you can create objects to interact with Microsoft Office.

EDIT:

I've found the documentation for WSH fairly lacking, especially for JScript examples. Recently I wrote a script to print all files in a folder and subfolders, had to use JScript because my target machine was under similar restrictions to yours. Check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/3040683) for the source, it should give you a rough idea of how WSH scripts can work.

Beyond that, you can interact with Excel, for example, by calling `CreateObject("Excel.Application")` and using the returned object. I had to do this once, but that code belongs to a former employer and I can't remember the specifics beyond grabbing an Excel instance.

Answer (score 4):

VBScript (WSH/CSCRIPT), Batch (MS Command Shell typically referred to as DOS), through Office Applications themselves you have VBA (Visual Basic for Applications)